# Flutter - Load path from gallery image

Tags: flutter

How can I load a image from gallery by Flutter?

For example, I have:

```
 final logo = Image.asset(
    '//storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181122_181848.jpg',
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    height: 230.0,
  );
```

This does not work.
I understand that this will only work in Android.
I prefer a good option for Android and iOS, but I don't know how.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: You seem to mix things up. Either you use assets, then you can use `Image.asset()` or you use a file with `Image.file()`. The way you mix it can't work. For assets see https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images Asset and file is not the same.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the example is wrong.
But, I remember that I used Image.file and I have the same problem. When I have my laptop I update the correct example.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

```
var file = new File('/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181122_181848.jpg');
return Image.file(file);
```

So: It is important to use Image.file and the absolute path has 1 "/" in the first position not 2.

:)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, There is an image_picker module that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can load an image with image picker package https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker.

First you should choose your image by writing:

```dart
FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(); 
if (result != null) 
   File image = File(result.files.single.path);
```

Second you should view your image:

```dart
Image.file(image);
```